# Будет ли плюсом опыт разработки Unity игр для десктоп c# developer?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Обучаюсь разработке программного обеспечения под Windows, сейчас наступил некий кризис в учебе и пришла в голову мысль, что могу попробовать Unity так чисто для того чтобы подтянуть знания c# в момент времени, когда совсем нет идей для десктопа, стоит ли пробовать?

Comment: Пробовать стоит, но при собеседовании это как послужной список сыграет в плюс только если вакансия будет на разработку игр. Всё-таки для обычных разработчиков разработка игр особо ничего не даёт - вы получаетесь и не бэкэндщик и не фрондэндщик, а что-то другое. Сами то знания языка, конечно, пригодятся. А знание Unity пригодится если только им дальше и заниматься идти.

Comment: Вряд ли Unity сильно поможет подтянуть C#

Comment: `...чисто для того чтобы подтянуть знания c# в момент времени, когда совсем нет идей для десктопа...` - если нет идей, то изучайте DDD, TDD, BDD, построение правильной архитектуры приложений.